# How to properly instantiate a module and pass registers to it

Tags: verilog, xilinx-ise

[![Simulation: modules seem to be running but not passing/recieving appropriate info?][1]][1]

I'm trying to become familiar with the Xilinx iSim utility. I am comfortable simulating a single, self contained module. However, when I begin introducing and instantiating multiple modules, I get unexpected results. The lower module `BCD_sevseg` does not appear to be accepting any input as it's clock will not cycle at all, let alone in sync with the top module clock

I am unsure of exactly how to structure the test bench but I'm sure there is a more fundamental issue with my understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish. However, previous attempts with similar structures implemented perfectly fine and my FPGA operated as expected.

I've verified the appropriate values are passed in an appropriate order and I don't receive any errors or warning upon a syntax check or simulation.

My top module is "instantiating" (is this the correct word) the `BCD_sevseg` module as follows

`BCD_sevseg` is supposed to accept `clk` (probably bad practice), a four bit number, and return the appropriate combination of LED states for the equivalent decimal number

There's most likely a lot of "accepted practices" I'm violating here, but I'm really just trying to get the test bench to operate properly at the moment.

I believe these are the requested modules.

TEST BENCH

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps



module mod_10_II_sim;

    reg clk;
    
    reg clock;
    reg [3:0] bin_sevseg_value;

    wire led_a;
    wire led_b;
    wire led_c;
    wire led_d;
    wire led_e;
    wire led_f;
    wire led_g;
    
    
    wire a;
    wire b;
    wire c;
    wire d;
    wire e;
    wire f;
    wire g;

    
    BCD_sevseg inst_one(
        .clock(clock),
        .bin_sevseg_value(bin_sevseg_value),
        .a(a),
        .b(b),
        .c(c),
        .d(d),
        .e(e),
        .f(f),
        .g(g)
        );
    
    mod_10_top uut (
        .clk(clk), 
        .led_a(led_a), 
        .led_b(led_b), 
        .led_c(led_c), 
        .led_d(led_d), 
        .led_e(led_e), 
        .led_f(led_f), 
        .led_g(led_g)
    );
            

    initial begin

        clk = 0;
        clock = 0;
        bin_sevseg_value = 0;
        
        #100;
        
        

    end
    always #10 clk = ~clk;
endmodule
```

TOP MODULE

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module BCD_sevseg( clock, bin_sevseg_value, a, b, c, d, e, f, g);

        input clock;
        input [3:0] bin_sevseg_value;
        
        output a;
        output b;
        output c;
        output d;
        output e;
        output f;
        output g;
        
        reg A = 1'b0;
        reg [0:0] B;
        reg [0:0] C;
        reg [0:0] D;
        reg [0:0] E;
        reg [0:0] F;
        reg [0:0] G;

        assign a = A;
        assign b = B;
        assign c = C;
        assign d = D;
        assign e = E;
        assign f = F;
        assign g = G;
        
        always @(posedge clock) begin
            
            case (bin_sevseg_value) 
                4'b0000: begin
                            A <= 1;
                            B <= 1;
                            C <= 1;         
                            D <= 1;
                            E <= 1;
                            F <= 1;
                            G <= 0;
                            end
                            
                4'b0001: begin
                            A <= 0;
                            B <= 1;
                            C <= 1;         
                            D <= 0;
                            E <= 0;
                            F <= 0;
                            G <= 0;
                            end
                        
                4'b0010: begin
                            A <= 1;
                            B <= 1;
                            C <= 0;         
                            D <= 1;
                            E <= 1;
                            F <= 0;
                            G <= 1;
                            end
                        
                4'b0011: begin
                            A <= 1;
                            B <= 1;
                            C <= 1;         
                            D <= 1;
                            E <= 0;
                            F <= 0;
                            G <= 1;
                            end
            
                4'b0100: begin
                            A <= 0;
                            B <= 1;
                            C <= 1;         
                            D <= 0;
                            E <= 0;
                            F <= 1;
                            G <= 1;
                            end
                        
                4'b0101: begin
                            A <= 1;
                            B <= 0;
                            C <= 1;         
                            D <= 1;
                            E <= 0;
                            F <= 1;
                            G <= 1;
                            end
                        
                4'b0110: begin
                            A <= 1;
                            B <= 0;
                            C <= 1;         
                            D <= 1;
                            E <= 1;
                            F <= 1;
                            G <= 1;
                            end
                        
                4'b0111: begin
                            A <= 1;
                            B <= 1;
                            C <= 1;         
                            D <= 0;
                            E <= 0;
                            F <= 0;
                            G <= 0;
                            end
                        
                4'b1000: begin
                            A <= 1;
                            B <= 1;
                            C <= 1;     
                            D <= 1;
                            E <= 1;
                            F <= 1;
                            G <= 1;
                            end
                        
                4'b1001: begin
                            A <= 1;
                            B <= 1;
                            C <= 1;     
                            D <= 1;
                            E <= 0;
                            F <= 1;
                            G <= 1;
                            end
                        
                default: begin
                            A <= 0;
                            B <= 1;
                            C <= 1;     
                            D <= 0;
                            E <= 1;
                            F <= 1;
                            G <= 1;
                            end     
        
            endcase
            
        end                             
        
endmodule                       
            
        
module mod_10_top( clk, led_a, led_b, led_c, led_d, led_e, led_f, led_g );

    input clk;

    output led_a;
    output led_b;
    output led_c;
    output led_d;
    output led_e;
    output led_f;
    output led_g;

    reg [9:0] counter;

    reg [3:0] seven_segment_digit;

    assign led_a = state_a;
    assign led_b = state_b;
    assign led_c = state_c;
    assign led_d = state_d;
    assign led_e = state_e;
    assign led_f = state_f;
    assign led_g = state_g; 
    
    
    /*-------------END DECLARATIONS----------------*/
        
    BCD_sevseg inst_one( clk, seven_segment_digit, state_a, state_b, state_c, state_d, state_e, state_f, state_g);
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
        end
    
    always @(posedge counter[8]) begin
        
        for(seven_segment_digit = 4'b0000; seven_segment_digit < 4'b1010; seven_segment_digit = seven_segment_digit + 4'b0001) begin
            end
        end
endmodule


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mJBH.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connected the wrong signal to the `BCD_sevseg` instance in the testbench module `mod_10_II_sim`.  In the testbench, you only toggle the `clk` signal, but not the `clock` signal.

Change:

```
BCD_sevseg inst_one(
    .clock(clock),
```

to:

```
BCD_sevseg inst_one(
    .clock(clk),
```

You should see a clock toggling in all instance of all modules.

---

Note: you should explicitly declare all your `state_` signals because my simulator gave me compile errors.

```
wire state_a;
wire state_b;
// etc.
```